# Simple twitter bootstrap navbar dropdown doesn't show the dropdown and instead extends the height of the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a created the following JSFiddle to duplicate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/7QExz/

The following is my code for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="padding: 0;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teams <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see, when you click on the drop down, it doesn't show any dropdown menu and instead, increases the height of the container and adds a horizontal scroll-bar to the dropdown button.

However, if you decrease the amount of available space and force the navbar to create a mobile-style collapse button on the right side, the dropdown works fine.

I'm unable to understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `style="overflow-y: hidden;"` on the outer `ul` element.

The `ul` element inherits it's height from the `navbar` class. Setting an `overflow: hidden` on the `ul` element causes anything that is to be displayed outside the height defined by the `navbar` class to be hidden.

Comment: I was about to ask why this was downvoted, considering the fact that this works, but @Jhawins explained the reason for the downvote. Thank you for the help, but a small explanation would definitely help :)

Comment: Sorry, added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

By using `overflow-y: hidden`, you're telling the browser to hide anything that goes beyond the height of the element, and if necessary, show a horizontal scrollbar. In this case, clicking on the dropmenu shows the menu, but the dropmenu's width is larger than the Teams element. If you remove that, then the dropmenu in tablet/desktop views will appear correctly.

In the mobile view, `padding: 0` causes the horizontal scrollbar to appear. Bootstrap's grid system works with negative margins, with equally positive paddings. By changing the left and right padding from 15px to 0, you're negating the offset of the left and right margin of -15px, causing horizontal scrollbars.

Removing both `padding: 0` and `overflow-y: hidden` will result in the menu behaving just like Bootstrap intended. If you're trying to accomplish something other than what Bootstrap has designed, that fact hasn't been made that clear.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QExz/1/).

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted as it identifies why the scrollbars appear in the various viewing styles.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `style="overflow-y: hidden;"` I'm not sure why that was there in the first place.

http://jsfiddle.net/7QExz/2/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="padding: 0;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teams <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```